# Run Chrome with "first/only parameter"

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey

I have search for a "first/only" parameter in this chrome list of parameters
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#load-extension

but I can't find it
does anybody know how to run google with "first/only" parameter?
I mean, if chrome window doesn't exist then run it, but if it is already open, don't open another instance of chrome, but just focus on it.

this parameter is called "first/only" in other programs like IrfanView
Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking... Are you only looking for a command line parameter for Chrome?  If so, why did you tag this with AutoHotKey?

Comment: He's looking to only open chrome, when it's not already open.... whch in windows 10 is the default behaviour, but hasn't specified what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

This small script will do the job.

```
#NoTrayIcon

if (WinExist("ahk_exe chrome.exe")) {
    WinActivate ahk_exe chrome.exe
} else {
    Run "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
}
```

Comment: yes its a workaround, but there isn't a paramater for that am I right?

Comment: @Natysiu16 I have no idea. You can try to check list of chrome switches to see if there is anything interesting https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: ok, I did it that way, but I already knew that workaround, could you please help me with this question? 
 https://superuser.com/questions/1313185/how-to-make-a-conditional-test-with-a-pseudo-array